# Regex to replace all empty JSON array values with null

Tags: java, regex, json

I am given a JSON array with some values being empty.  Instead of null, these values are currently just empty, which makes the JSON invalid.  For example:

```
[
    "Name",
    ,
    "card",
    ,
    ,
    342,
    2334,
    0
]
```

If possible, I'm looking for a regular expression to replace the empty space with null:

```
[
    "Name",
    null,
    "card",
    null,
    null,
    342,
    2334,
    0
]
```

The new lines and indentation are not present in the actual JSON.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java regular expressions.

Comment: `,,` => `,null,` and `,]` => `,null]`?

Comment: What if I had `,,,`?  It would replace it with `,null,,` but there would still be two consecutive commas left.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing any empty string or whitespace preceded and followed by a comma (or by `[` or `]` if it occurs exactly at the beginning or end of the list) with null.
It should work whether the actual JSON string has whitespace or not.

```
String result = str.replaceAll("(?<=,|\\[)\\s*(?=,|\\])","null")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this one just remove the fields instead of replacing with `null`?  Shouldn't it be replaced by `"null,"`?

Comment: This is right now.  I missed the note of no whitespace in OP, but I'll leave my answer up there for reference.

Comment: +1. This works for the sample input. But won't replace if it's the first one, which OP doesn't mention. :)

Comment: @BheshGurung: you're correct, it wouldn't work if it's the last either, edited.

Comment: What about inside a string?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This works if you have whitespace like in your OP.  Otherwise, you'll want to use @anana's answer or @BillCriswell's comment.

Replace:

```
^(\s*)(?=,)
```

With:

```
$1null
```

This looks at the beginning of each line (`^`), followed by capturing 0+ whitespace characters (`(\s*)`), while looking ahead to see that the next character is a comma (`(?=,)`).

This will need to be a global match (`g` modifier) and, depending on the language, you may need to make `^` match each new line (`m` modifier).

Example: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wV0kL9)

Comment: I think this wouldn't work as there is no whitespace in the actual file.